# What kind of delays are to be expected when opening bluetooth sockets?

Tags: sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to optimize some code that I have that requires me to try and contact a few bluetooth devices using RFCOMM. Right now it's taking at least 2 seconds to successfully open a socket to any of the devices. Is this kind of delay normal?